# How to group columns in pandas as given categories?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, time-series

Let's say that I have a set of columns and I want to group them  only for indexing purposes. For example I have dataframe `df` with 26 columns called from `["A",...,"Z"]` and its rows are occurrence of the letter in a  documents.

Now I'd like to split the dataframe between "Vowels" and "Consonants" in a way that I could get the dataframe with only vowels with something like `df["Vowels"]` or `df[["Vowels"]]`. Namely, is there a *multi-index* approach for this problem or any other pandas tool? I know that a simple solution would be defining `Vowels=["a",..."y"]` and then do `df[Vowels]`, but I'd like to use pandas features if available.

Another example is a timeseries of temperature from different sensors in different cities and I'd like to get a table that looks like this:
[image]
So that in my analysis I can just do `df[['City 1]].plot()` and I can quickly navigate in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Pandas has a robust system for [MultiIndexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).  One way to do what you want is as follows:

```
vowels = ['A','E','I','O','U','Y']
tuples = [('Vowel' if x in vowels else 'Consonant', x) for x in df.columns.tolist()]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Kind', 'Letter'])
```

First you make a list of vowels (you may need to include letters with accents, diacritics, etc., depending on your use case).  Then you make a list of tuples where the first value is either `'Vowel'` or `'Consonant'` and the second value is the letter for every letter in your column list.  Then you make a MultiIndex out of those tuples.